# How can I restrict the normal user to run only limited set of commands in RHEL?

Tags: shell, rhel, ls, restricted-shell

How can I restrict the Normal user to run the only limited set of commands in RHEL?

Comment: restricted shell, containers, chroot...the question is too broad.

Answer (score 4):

You can force the user to use a *[restricted shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_shell)*.

Option #1 - [How to: Configure User Account to Use a Restricted Shell ( rssh )](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-restrict-shell-access-with-rssh.html)

---

Option #2 - [Here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/65822) is a description **made by RedHat** how to do it in RHEL

> **Disclaimer : This is just a hack, not recommended for Actual Production Use**
>
> The normal user has been given permission to execute some commands
>   which are available in /bin/ and /usr/local/bin/, So to remove those
>   permissions and to restrict the user to run only particular set of
>   commands, following steps shall be useful.
>
> 1. Create the restricted shell.
>
>    ```
>    # cp /bin/bash /bin/rbash
>    ```
> 2. Modify the target user for the shell as restricted shell
>
> While creating user:
>
> ```
>     # useradd -s /bin/rbash localuser
> ```
>
> For existing user:
>
> ```
>     # usermod -s /bin/rbash localuser
> ```
>
> For more detailed information on this, please check the KBase Article
>   8349
>
> Then the user localuser is chrooted and can't access the links outside
>   his home directory /home/localuser
>
> 3. Create a directory under /home/localuser/, e.g. programs
>
>    ```
>    # mkdir /home/localuser/programs
>    ```
> 4. Now if you check, the user localuser can access all commands which he/she has allowed to execute. These commands are taken from the
>      environmental PATH variable which is set in
>      /home/localuser/.bash_profile. Modify it as follows.
>
>    ```
>    # cat /home/localuser/.bash_profile  
>    # .bash_profile  
>
>    # Get the aliases and functions  
>    if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then  
>    . ~/.bashrc  
>    fi  
>    # User specific environment and startup programs  
>    PATH=$HOME/programs  
>    export PATH
>    ```
>
> Here the PATH variable is set to ~/programs directory, as
>   /usr/local/bin is binded to /home/username/bin and /bin is binded to
>   /home/username/bin so replacing that.
>
> 5. Now after logging with the username localuser, user cant run a simple command too. The output will be like this,
>
>    ```
>    [localuser@example ~]$ ls  
>    -rbash: ls: command not found  
>    [localuser@example ~]$ less file1  
>    -rbash: less: command not found  
>    [localuser@example ~]$ clear  
>    -rbash: clear: command not found  
>    [localuser@example ~]$ date  
>    -rbash: date: command not found  
>    [localuser@example ~]$ ping redhat.com  
>    -rbash: ping: command not found
>    ```
> 6. Now create the softlinks of commands which are required for user localuser to execute in the directory /home/localuser/programs
>
>    ```
>    # ln -s /bin/date /home/localuser/programs/  
>    # ln -s /bin/ls /home/localuser/programs/  
>    # ll /home/localuser/programs/  
>    total 8  
>    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Oct 17 15:53 date -> /bin/date  
>    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Oct 17 15:43 ls -> /bin/ls
>    ```
>
> Here examples of date and ls commands has been taken
>
> 7. Again login with user localuser and try to execute the commands.
>
>    ```
>    [localuser@example ~]$ date  
>    Mon Oct 17 15:55:45 IST 2011  
>    [localuser@example ~]$ ls  
>    file1 file10 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 file7 file8 file9 programs  
>    [localuser@example ~]$ clear  
>    -rbash: clear: command not found
>    ```
> 8. One more step can be added to restrict the user for making any modifications in their .bash_profile , as users can change it.
>
> Run the following command to make the user localuser's .bash_profile
>   file as immutable so that root/localuser can't modify it until root
>   removes immutable permission from it.
>
> ```
>     # chattr +i /home/localuser/.bash_profile
> ```
>
> To remove immutable tag,
>
> ```
>     # chattr -i /home/localuser/.bash_profile
> ```
>
> Make file .bash_profile as immutable so that user localuser can't
>   change the environmental paths.