# How to restrict users so that they can only execute commands from /bin?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, non-root-user, restricted-shell

I was provided an assignment with several questions. One of the questions is:

> How to restrict users can only execute the commands in the directory `/bin`?

I tried to solve it by using the following commands, but they did not work.

```
# useradd -s /bin/bash localuser
# usermod -s /bin/rbash localuser
# mkdir /home/localuser/programs
```

Here are the contents of `/home/localuser/.bash_profile`:

```bash
# .bash_profile  

# Get the aliases and functions  
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then  
. ~/.bashrc  
fi  
# User specific environment and startup programs  
PATH=$HOME/programs  
export PATH
```

Then I tried:

```
[localuser@example ~]$ ls  
-rbash: ls: command not found  
[localuser@example ~]$ less file1  
-rbash: less: command not found  
[localuser@example ~]$ clear  
-rbash: clear: command not found  
[localuser@example ~]$ date  
-rbash: date: command not found  
[localuser@example ~]$ ping redhat.com  
-rbash: ping: command not found
# ln -s /bin/date /home/localuser/programs/  
# ln -s /bin/ls /home/localuser/programs/  
# ll /home/localuser/programs/  
total 8  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Oct 17 15:53 date -> /bin/date  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Oct 17 15:43 ls -> /bin/ls
[localuser@example ~]$ date  
Mon Oct 17 15:55:45 IST 2011  
[localuser@example ~]$ ls  
file1 file10 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 file7 file8 file9 programs  
[localuser@example ~]$ clear  
-rbash: clear: command not found
# chattr +i /home/localuser/.bash_profile
```

What would be your answer?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you followed precisely either [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/428190/423679) or the [guide it links to](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/65822). But they specifically show how to restrict user to be able to run only specific commands. In their examples those commands where `date` and `ls`. But your question is different because you want the user to be able to run all commands from `/bin`, not just specific commands. So, instead of linking separate commands, you want to link the whole directory. You should be able to do it with `ln`.